# three js rotating objects around a sphere

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, trigonometry

So I have been working with threejs recently and ran into some issues when trying to rotate a globe with mini spheres on the surface of the globe.

https://github.com/rohanbhangui/globe-webgl <-- my code can be found here

this is a temp link but for those who want to see my stuff in action: https://cucmfjedgt.localtunnel.me

So what is **suppose** to happen:

- user can rotate the globe with their mouse and the group which holds the globe and everything in the scene rotates according to the mouse movement
- when a user clicks on a green blob a conditional part of the mouseup event is fired and the globe (along with the green blobs) will rotate such that the clicked green blob will now be in the center of the screen

I have tried nearly everything (except for the solution of course :) )

your help is much appreciated. (Please bear with my code I know its messy)

Comment: I see your code work, atleast in Firefox, can you explain more

Comment: so basically as I said before, I want to have the sphere rotate so that when i click on of the green blobs, the blob that is clicked gets centered

Comment: Ah, so you may want to get coordinate of the green blob and then rotate the big globe so that green blob is at the center of the screen?

Comment: yes, I have already been able to figure out the 3d position of the green blob and the center where i want the green blob to show and i tried using some basic functions to execute transformations but it just isnt working, any ideas?

Comment: Dead link, would you please update your question @RohanBhangui

Comment: @TOPKAT unfortunately I do not have the code anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooooooo 8 years later I have come back full circle (same problem different project) and wanted to share a solution with others that seemed to work for me.

Basically I ended up using `three-globe` package since I am coding it in react with `react-three-fiber`. But then I pulled [this](https://github.com/vasturiano/globe.gl/blob/f805a3da6ab04ace4bb7ec432a0841b49eae52e0/src/globe.js#L251) code to achieve the rotation I required once the scene loads. Still trying to figure how this magic works but very thankful to that package, check it out!

And thanks to those that provided solutions below, some great stuff!

Answer (score 4):

I guess you work with latitude, attitude points. I calculte the phi, theta as follow:

```
var phi = (90 - varible1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var theta = (-variable2) * Math.PI / 180;
    var RandomHeightOfLine = 1.5 // Or greater then your point distance to origin
```

As Vector =

```
new THREE.Vector3(RandomHeightOfLine * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta), RandomHeightOfLine * Math.cos(phi), RandomHeightOfLine * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta)));
```

As Point =

```
var x = RandomHeightOfLine * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
var y = RandomHeightOfLine * Math.cos(phi);
var z = RandomHeightOfLine * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
controls.target.set( x, y, z );
```

If you want to move the camera also I'd suggest to calculate x2,y2,z2 with greater RandomHeightOfLine.

Further more if you want smooth move I suggest you to use TWEEN.

```
                var t;
                var t2;
                var t3; //Put as Global or use Array, because GC likes to remove Tween objects.
                function tweenCamera(position, target, time){
                    console.log("tween");
                    updateTween = true;
                    beforeTweenPos = camera.position.clone();
                    beforeTweenTarg = controls.target.clone();
                    t = new TWEEN.Tween( camera.position ).to( {
                        x: position.x,
                        y: position.y,
                        z: position.z}, time )
                    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.In).start();
                    t2 = new TWEEN.Tween( camera.up ).to( {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 1,
                        z: 0}, time )
                    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.In).start();
                    t3 = new TWEEN.Tween( controls.target ).to( {
                        x: target.x,
                        y: target.y,
                        z: target.z}, time )
                    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.In)
                    .onComplete(function () {
                        updateTween = false;
                        console.log("Turning off Update Tween");
                        t = null;
                        t2 = null;
                        t3 = null;
                    }, this).start();

                    //camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1); //  If you don't want animation for this. And remove t3. 
                }
```

Also your animation update you should put:

```
...
                            lastTimeMsec    = lastTimeMsec || nowMsec-1000/60;
                            deltaMsec   = Math.min(200, nowMsec - lastTimeMsec);
                            lastTimeMsec    = nowMsec;
                                if(updateTween)
                                {
                                    TWEEN.update(lastTimeMsec); //Comment
                                } else 
                                {
                                    TWEEN.removeAll();
                                }
...
```

Tween JS: http://www.createjs.com/tweenjs

Answer (score 0):

Hey you already did that in your code, I just copy from your creation, see your example here

http://www.nhutrinh.com/threejs/

```
if(intersects.length >= 3)
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < vlist.length; i++)
      {
        if(vlist[i][0].position === intersects[0].object.position)
        {
          console.log("that point exists! code for rotating to green blob goes below");
             targetRotationY = targetRotationYOnMouseDown + ( mouse.y - mouseYOnMouseDown ) * 0.01 *75/targetDistance;
             targetRotationX = targetRotationXOnMouseDown + ( mouse.x - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.01 *75/targetDistance;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to rotate properly, as it isnt going to the center which is my problem